# Extend the hierarchy of a class present in an external library

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus

Let's say you have an external library that you can't modify, like this one (it's a demo code):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TPasElement=class
    ElementInfo : string;
  end;

  TPasConst=class(TPasElement)
    ConstInfo : string;
  end;

  TPasVariable=class(TPasElement)
    VariableInfo : string;
  end;

  TPasType=class(TPasElement)
    TypeInfo : string;
  end;

  TPasProperty=class(TPasElement)
    PropertyInfo : string;
  end;

  TPasProcedure=class(TPasElement)
    ProcedureInfo : string;
  end;


implementation

end.
```

In my program I need to process (for example display) the different possible TPasElement. A very inelegant way would be the following:

```
procedure Process(Element : TPasElement);
begin
  if Element is TPasConst then
    writeln(TPasConst(Element).ConstInfo)
  else if Element is TPasVariable then
    writeln(TPasVariable(Element).VariableInfo)
  else if Element is TPasType then
    writeln(TPasType(Element).TypeInfo)
  else if Element is TPasProperty then
    writeln (TPasProperty(Element).PropertyInfo)
  else if Element is TPasProcedure then
    writeln(TPasProcedure(Element).ProcedureInfo);
end;
```

I'm looking for a more elegant way that takes advantage of inheritance / polymorphism (possibly a design pattern), which allows me to achieve the same thing. I don't want to use class helpers. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Normally declare a virtual abstract function, perhaps named ToString and override it in each derived class to return that specific value. Literally polymorphism 101! But yeah, if you can't change the classes then your are stuck with your current approach. You lost the chance for elegance once you were unable to modify the class design.

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, I also thought about polymorphism, with the introduction of an abstract virtual function in the base class and its override in the derived classes. But this assumes you are modifying the library. I thought we could use some design patterns or use interfaces. But I don't find a solution.

Comment: @simone you can't use interfaces without changing the declarations of the classes to implement the interfaces, which you are not able to do. Without that ability, what you already have is about all you can do (unless you have access to RTTI for the classes).

Comment: Thanks Remy. At this point, I wonder if it might be more efficient, instead of a sequence of 'if then else' with the logical condition expressed by the 'is' operator, to use Classname in a 'case' statement  What do you think?

Comment: You can't use a case statement that switches based on string data types. But even if you could the code would essentially be just the same.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm using FreePascal, that supports case statement with string. However I agree with you: basically it's the same code. As a side note: I don't understand why Delphi hasn't introduced this feature yet.

Comment: @Simone: the classname solution will only trigger if a class is really the type oif the tested string (e.g. TPasProcedure). The _IS_ solution will also work if you pass derivatives of TPasProcedure to Process().  Source for FCL-Passrc is available.

Comment: Thanks Marco. You understand the context, which is about using fcl-passrc. I can certainly modify the sources, because they are available, but since they are updated often, I should then periodically merge my changes with those of the maintainers.